# How to place edittext in a new line when edge reached

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I am creating textviews programatically with code below. My problem is that they are all squeezed together in one line whereas I want that when the edge is reached, they immediately go to the next line.

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_answerboxes);

        final EditText[] answerboxes = new EditText[answerSplit.size()];
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(125, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        for (int i = 0; i<answerSplit.size(); i++) {
            answerboxes[i] = new EditText(getActivity());
            answerboxes[i].setLayoutParams(lparams);
            answerboxes[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ll.addView(answerboxes[i]);
        }
```

current behavior

[image: current behavior]

wanted behavior

[image: wanted behavior]

my current workaround is to use a second linearlayout for the second line but was wondering if there was a way to manipulate the first linearlayout so that a second linearlayout won't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Measure your width of a screen and measure your edit text width with margins etc. And you can calculate whether is enough space for a new edittext or not.
When have reached an edge I would add a new linear layout.

In an xml it would look like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--Your edit texts from first row-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--Your edit texts from second row-->

    </LinearLayout>


    .....

</LinearLayout>
```

You could add as much rows as you want.

Comment: yeah. I currently have that as my workaround but was wondering if there was some other way to do it. Thanks though!

Comment: Maybe a GridView with Edit Texts.